# Whenever i do "heavy" suff, PC runs very slow & laggy. Is there a way to solve this by Partitioning?

Tags: dual-boot, freeze, 18.10

I have only three partitions:

> Swap (13.5 GB), Root (70 GB) and Home (150 GB).

**Note: This is Ubuntu 18.10 dual booted with Windows 10.**

> I have 8 GB of RAM. Intel i5 processor.

- I have heard about other partition tables like Temp, etc. So I was
  hoping to create some partition to resolve this.
- Or maybe I need to increase Swap memory.
- P.S: I don't want my PC to crash because it can't handle things. Sometimes I can't even use my cursor because it's responding too slow! There gotta be some way to solve this.
- (This issue generated when I used *TestDisk* to recover my hard
  disk.)

---

> Some outputs which might be helpful:

---

---

```
pranav@inspiron-5548:~$ inxi -Fxz
System:
  Host: inspiron-5548 
  Kernel: 4.18.0-15-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  compiler: gcc v: 8.2.0 Desktop: Gnome 3.30.1 
  Distro: Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish) 
Machine:
  Type: Portable System: Dell 
  product: Inspiron 5548 v: A09 
  serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: Dell model: 0FFJC4 v: A00 
  serial: <filter> UEFI: Dell v: A09 
  date: 05/15/2018 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 12.4 Wh 
  condition: 15.0/44.5 Wh (34%) 
  model: SDI DELL VVMKC52A status: Discharging 
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core 
  model: Intel Core i5-5200U bits: 64 
  type: MT MCP arch: Broadwell rev: 4 
  L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
  flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 
  ssse3 vmx 
  bogomips: 17559 
  Speed: 798 MHz min/max: 500/2700 MHz 
  Core speeds (MHz): 1: 798 2: 798 3: 798 
  4: 798 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 5500 
  driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.1 
  driver: fbdev unloaded: modesetting,vesa 
  resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 
  5500 (Broadwell GT2) 
  v: 4.5 Mesa 18.2.2 direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Broadwell-U Audio 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
  bus ID: 00:03.0 
  Device-2: Intel Wildcat Point-LP High 
  Definition Audio 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
  bus ID: 00:1b.0 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.18.0-15-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast 
  Ethernet 
  driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 3000 
  bus ID: 02:00.0 
  IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Intel Wireless 3160 
  driver: iwlwifi v: kernel bus ID: 03:00.0 
  IF: wlp3s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
  IF-ID-1: wlxd46e0e0f6870 state: up 
  mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB 
  used: 54.83 GiB (5.9%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Toshiba 
  model: MQ01ABD100 size: 931.51 GiB 
  temp: 29 C 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 74.60 GiB 
  used: 15.50 GiB (20.8%) fs: ext4 
  dev: /dev/sda6 
  ID-2: /home size: 125.69 GiB 
  used: 39.29 GiB (31.3%) fs: ext4 
  dev: /dev/sda7 
  ID-3: swap-1 size: 13.26 GiB 
  used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda5 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 45.0 C mobo: N/A 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0 
Info:
  Processes: 247 Uptime: 18m Memory: 7.71 GiB 
  used: 2.42 GiB (31.3%) Init: systemd 
  runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 8.2.0 
  Shell: bash v: 4.4.19 inxi: 3.0.24
```

Comment: Why did you need to recover your hard disk? Isn’t the performance of your hard disk simply worsening because it’s dying?

Comment: A nice way to present information about your system is to install *inxi* and to post the output of *inxi -Fxz*.

Comment: @DKBose the question is now updated.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way round that I'm afraid unless you upgrade your processor etc. to complete the tasks quicker. If your recovering the hard disk whilst it's in use it's always going to slow down the system, as you say it's a heavy workload. Partitioning isn't going to give you a magic speed boost I'm afraid because again it's on the disk, again the swap partition is using space on the hard drive as virtual ram so is also going to be significantly slower than actual ram and not really create any boost in speed during any workload and especially not during heavy workloads. Recovering any disk particularly if it's the main hard drive of the system in use is always best done when you can just set it off and leave it to finish by itself.

Comment: Upgrading the processor won't help much. The limit is the number of IOPS a physical disk can do, probably around 100 - 150 for a consumer laptop disk. Upgrade to a SSD will help though, it would handle 1000's of IOPS.

Comment: @Soren A Fair enough it was the first thing that came to mind. Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think there's really any way to significantly improve things without putting together an really high end PC. If your putting the hard drive through that sort of workload it's always going to have a significant impact on performance.

Comment: Upgrading the HDD to SSD helps. Every thing loads faster, and if swapping that is much faster too. If the machine is paging / swapping a lot, more RAM will help too.